# Sudden disappearance of close votes on a post

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, comments, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675476/inputtype-submit-i-what-is-i-and-this-syntax#44675517) on Stack Overflow is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506735/what-does-i-mean-in-a-css-attribute-selector/27507191), so I voted to close it as a duplicate. After my closing vote, there were a couple of other votes there as well.

But after some time, I noticed that now this post doesn't show any close votes. And the comment with the text **"Possible Duplicate Of..."** is also gone.

[image: Image of Post].

If I try to close this question again then it shows that I've already voted to close this question.

[image: Image of Post]

I'm surprised to see this. Can someone please explain this mystery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The post was closed by the community, then reopened.

You can see this in the [revisions history of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44675476/revisions) or [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44675476/timeline).

Comment: And it was reopened by the gold badge holder who *has an answer on the question.* Of all people *he* should know better. Wow.

Comment: And not any "an answer" but essentially exact duplicate of answers in suggested duplicate... *Oded* - would re-open/posting duplicate answer be good case to flag for moderator attention in general (clearly two mods already seen this particular one)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - something blatant like this? Yes, absolutely.